# Run PHP script with CRON

Tags: php, debian, cron

I try to run PHP scripts on my debian server, everyday at midnight & 1 minute.

So I created the crontab file in admin, with

```
crontab -e
```

who seems to be in

```
/tmp/crontab.ky3Q3F/crontab
```

And I put the line

```
01 00 * * * /usr/bin/php5 /var/www/MySite/cronTB.php
```

Bellow the comments.
The goal is to run cronTB.php (with PHP) everyday at 0h01.

Is my syntax correct ?

Is the correct file to edit, to the correct path ?

Is the CRON daemon still runing after I run it with:

```
/etc/init.d/cron start
```

even if I close the ssh connexion ?

Thanks for help

Comment: Yes to every question you asked.

Comment: But the scripts aren't call since 3 days...

Comment: Then check to make sure the paths to the files you've outlined above is correct. There's no way for us to know that part.

Comment: The url /var/www/MySite/cronTB.php is correct, but maybe I have to call the http url of the site ?

Comment: What's the minimum permission required ?

Comment: in ssh run /usr/bin/php5 /var/www/MySite/cronTB.php and see what happens, also i write 1 0 * * * but it really doesn't matter

Comment: Check this debugging info: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info